# ansible privileges escalation become_method: value difference between 'sudo' and 'su'?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Look into this document: [ansible privileges escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/become.html)
In this doc it has mentioned:

> --become-method=BECOME_METHOD
>       privilege escalation method to use (default=sudo), valid choices: [ sudo | su | pbrun | pfexec | doas | dzdo | ksu | runas | machinectl ]

What is the difference between 'sudo' and 'su'? What is really happening underneath?

Take `run_command` on `remote_host` for example?

`become_method` approach is `sudo run_command` on the `remote_host`. Is it true? But I think `sudo` is not a `become to some user` method, `su` is.

What are they and what is the difference?

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sudo-vs-su/

Answer (score 2):

The `sudo` method uses the `sudo` command, and the `su` method uses the `su` command.  Both commands can be used to run commands as another user; compare:

```
sudo -u someuser echo hello world
```

With:

```
su someuser -c 'echo hello world'
```

They have slightly different semantics.  The `sudo` command is controlled by your `/etc/sudoers` file and can be configured to permit privilege escalation without a password.  Using `su` you will always need to provide a password using `--ask-become-pass` on the command line, or by setting the `ansible_become_pass` variable.

Comment: It's also important to note that current security standard practices recommend using sudo, and avoiding use of su.  It's easier to audit, and maintain accountability with sudo, as well as allowing fine grain control over which users/groups are allowed to run specific commands with elevated privileges.

Comment: When using Ansible, you are effectively unable to take advantage of either the auditing or the fine grained control, because Ansible doesn't apply `sudo` to individual commands; it uses `sudo` to launch your *module*, which then may run an arbitrary sequence of commands.  All you can control is whether or not Ansible is able to gain privileges.

Comment: Agreed.  Just like providing a little extra context for people who appear to be new, and may not be aware of why one would be chosen over the other.